# Resize Sheet.Range to Large 1D Array with VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, resize

Hoping this isn't a duplicate post, but I've not been able to find an answer to my problem. The code below is what I am currently running, but I'm trying to optimize the last bit which prints a 1D array, `myArray`, containining 100,000 rows of data, onto a sheet named `shHidden`.

The intent is to parse a string using an array by splitting a string, parsing elements of the array, then putting them into a second array. From there, the second array would be printed to two locations; 1) another string via Join(), and 2) a worksheet.

```
SplitTextBox1 = Split(shInterface.txt_Input, Chr(10))    

j = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(SplitTextBox1)
    
    j = j + 1
    
    ReDim Preserve MyArray(j)
                    
    MyArray(j) = SplitTextBox1(i)
        
Next i  

shInterface.txt_Output = Join(MyArray)
```

This is where I am struggling. I would like to print `myArray` to `shHidden` so that I can save it as a .CSV later, but each variation of `shHidden.Range("A1") .Resize(j) = myArray` is only printing the first element of `myArray` to each cell of shHidden.

This is what I currently do,

```
For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
    shHidden.Range("A" & i) = MyArray(i)
Next i
```

as opposed to something that might look like,

```
shHidden.Range("B1").Resize(i) = MyArray
```

I have tried `Transposing` the array, but it doesn't send 100% of the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx <~~ An excellent reference for these types of actions. - What do you mean by *it doesn't send 100% of the array*?

Comment: @SamuelEverson, thank you for the response. That's actually the reference that I have been trying to use. I think that my current issue is that myArray contains many rows, rather than many columns. I can't figure out how to apply the referenced material. Transpose does successfully list myArray, but only up until element 34,466. From 34,467 until 100,000 it prints "#N/A".

Comment: Transpose() has a limit of around 65k elements

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks. I did find that in another post. I'm really wanting to know if there is an alternative method for printing 100k elements without looping through each cell.

Comment: Instead of transposing the array with `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`, you need to transpose it by looping through the **array** (not the cells).  One requires a 2D array to write to a **column** of cells.

Comment: @Ron, thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I am going to try implementing and will update this post later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but should be close:

```vb
Dim arr, i As Long, SplitTextBox1

SplitTextBox1 = Split(shInterface.txt_Input, Chr(10))

ReDim arr(1 To UBound(SplitTextBox1) + 1, 1 To 1)

For i = 0 To UBound(SplitTextBox1)
    arr(i + 1, 1) = SplitTextBox1(i)
Next i

shInterface.txt_Output = Join(SplitTextBox1)

shHidden.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 1).Value = arr
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's returning a "Subscript out of range" on the first iteration of `arr(i + 1) = SplitTextBox1(i)`

Comment: Sorry I did already fix that - see above `arr(i + 1, 1) = SplitTextBox1(i)`

Comment: Awesome; out for groceries but will update you as soon as I am back home. Cheers!

Comment: Well, Tim, you've done it. Works like a charm. If we ever cross paths I'll be sure to have your eggs. Thank you!